# Using Firebase/MLVisionLabelModel in iOS project generates console warnings

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, firebase-mlkit

I have been recently messing around with the Firebase Beta ML Kit in my iOS project, and it's been quite an enjoyable experience so far.

However, when I include the `'Firebase/MLVisionLabelModel'` pod, I get tons of warnings that look like this

```
objc[4034]: Class GMVx_StringListParam is implemented in both /var/containers/Bundle/Application/19D40B05-8B99-4580-97F8-22B83C45D7FF/xxxxxx.app/xxxxxx (0x10243e368) and /var/containers/Bundle/Application/19D40B05-8B99-4580-97F8-22B83C45D7FF/xxxxxx.app/xxxxxx (0x102443e08). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Am I missing something here? What do these warnings refer to exactly?

Comment: This issue should be fixed in the latest version of ML Kit.  Could you try again?

Comment: Yes, should've updated this thread a while ago. Thanks for pointing it out @DongChen